# codeigniter 2.0 hybridAuth library integration

Tags: codeigniter, hybridauth

I have downloaded to use hybridauth's codeigniter library from sourceforge...I have done everything as readme.md file..But when I run the code,instead of logging in, it directs to my localhost..what's the problem u think ???

Comment: Please provide more information. There's not much to go on unless someone had the exact same problem. What is localhost in your case? Is it your document root? Do you get PHP erros? Have you tried turning on CI logging? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Comment: Sorry,Robert...I solved the localhost issue...thanks for your opinion...next time i will try to make my questions more elaborate & understandable..

Comment: Glad to hear that. Perhaps you could share your solution, so that the next person with this problem can find the answer. Thanks!